# Как вывести количество итераций в инпут?

Tags: javascript

```js
// Задача решается с помощью цикла. 
// В каждой итерации цикл выводит 6 звездочек без пробелов и символ переноса строки br.
// Количество строк (итераций, повторений) цикла вводит пользователь в i-6



function t6() {
  let inp6 = +document.querySelector('.i-6');
  for (let i = 0; i < 1; i = inp6.value) {
    document.querySelector('.out-6').innerHTML += '******' + '<br>';
    inp6.value = i;
  }
}

document.querySelector('.b-6').onclick = t6;
```

```html
<section>
  <p><b>Task 6.</b></p>
  <p>Кнопка b-6 запускает функцию t6. Функция должна выводить в out-6 строку вида: </p>
  <pre>
        ******<br>
        ******<br>
        ******<br>
      </pre>
  <p>
    Задача решается с помощью цикла. В каждой итерации цикл выводит 6 звездочек
    без пробелов и символ переноса строки br. Количество строк (итераций,
    повторений) цикла вводит пользователь в i-6.
  </p>
  <div class="form-control">Input i-6
    <input type="number" class="i-6">
  </div>
  <button class="button-primary b-6">Task-6</button>
  <div class="out-6"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: `+document.querySelector('.i-6')` заменить на `+document.querySelector('.i-6').value`, `for (let i = 0; i < 1; i = inp6.value)` - заменить на `for (let i = 0; i < inp6; i++)`, `inp6.value = i;` - удалить, и почитать про цикли.

Comment: и у вас в заголовке вопроса написано `вывести количество итераций в инпут` а в вопросе написано `Количество строк (итераций, повторений) цикла ВВОДИТ пользователь в i-6`. Вы определитесь...

Comment: это что за конструкция `let inp6 = +document.querySelector('.i-6');` ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изначально у Вас в поле `inp6.value` при вводе данных уже содержит то количество, сколько будет произведено операций.
Не совсем понятно с какой целью Вы хотите его менять.
В случае же крайне необходимости - Вы можете использовать счётчик, если внутри цикла будет ещё какое-либо условие.

```js
    function t6() {
        let inp6 = document.querySelector('.i-6');
        let count = 0; // Заводим счётчик(так как непонятно чего конкретно хотите этим добиться. Поле inp.value уже содержит нужное значение.)
        document.querySelector('.out-6').innerHTML = ''; // Очищаем поле.
        for (let i = 0; i < inp6.value; i++) { // inp6.value
            document.querySelector('.out-6').innerHTML += '******' + '<br>'; // Дописываем строку.
            count += 1;
        }
        inp6.value = count; // Записываем в поле счётчик. Вы в данное поле могли просто записать inp6.value = inp6.value; Но опять таки это поле УЖЕ содержит это значение, мы же оттуда его и взяли.
    }
    document.querySelector('.b-6').onclick = t6;
```

```html
<section>
    <p><b>Task 6.</b></p>
    <p>Кнопка b-6 запускает функцию t6. Функция должна выводить в out-6 строку вида: </p>
    <pre>
        ******<br>
        ******<br>
        ******<br>
      </pre>
    <p>
        Задача решается с помощью цикла. В каждой итерации цикл выводит 6 звездочек
        без пробелов и символ переноса строки br. Количество строк (итераций,
        повторений) цикла вводит пользователь в i-6.
    </p>
    <div class="form-control">Input i-6
        <input type="number" class="i-6">
    </div>
    <button class="button-primary b-6">Task-6</button>
    <div class="out-6"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @АлександрКедря на етом сайте благодарность принято выражать в виде принятия понравившегося ответа (галочка возле голосов)